# Returning Two Types from one Function using Protocol Conformance

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

```
protocol PriceCalculatable {}
extension Int : PriceCalculatable {}
extension Double : PriceCalculatable {}


class PriceCalculator {
   static func culculateFinalPrice<T: PriceCalculatable>(for products: [Product],
                                applying coupon: Coupon?) -> T {

    let x = products.reduce(0) { price, product in
        return price + product.price
    }

    var finalPrice = Double(x)

    if let coupon = coupon {
        let multiplier = coupon.discountPercentage / 100
        let discount = Double(finalPrice) * Double(multiplier)
        finalPrice -= Double(discount)
    }

    return finalPrice
   }
}
```

I'm receiving an error that says :

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Double' to return type 'T'

Although the Error makes sense, however, I don't understand why `Double` and `Int` conform to this type yet can't be returned

Comment: The definitions of `Product` and `Coupon` are missing

Comment: I don't think it relates to the solution that I am seeking, unless you can convince me otherwise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your method compiles,

Let's create another type that conforms to `PriceCalculatable`:

```
struct Foo : PriceCalculatable {}
```

Now we try to call your method:

```
let foo: Foo = PriceCalculator.culculateFinalPrice(for: someProducts, applying: myCoupon)
```

From the compiler's perspective, the above compiles, yet this results in an inconsistency at runtime. How can the runtime convert a `Double` (`finalPrice`) into a `Foo`?

Therefore, your method should not compile.

To make it work, you can create a `ConvertileFromDouble` protocol and make `Int` and `Double` conform to it. In the protocol, you need to specify an initialiser that takes a `Double` as argument.

```
protocol ConvertibleFromDouble {
    init(_ doubleValue: Double)
}

extension Int: ConvertibleFromDouble {

}

extension Double: ConvertibleFromDouble {

}

class PriceCalculator {
    static func culculateFinalPrice<T: ConvertibleFromDouble>(for products: [Product],
                                                          applying coupon: Coupon?) -> T {
        ...
```